# On click, Text of jLabel appears but not the Icon Image?

Tags: java, swing

When I click Print Button it should show a Gif Animation followed by the text "Working..."
but here only the text "Working..." appears , not the animation.

Here's the Code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    jLabel1.setVisible(true);
    /* This portion is Time Consuming so I want to display a Loading gif animation. */
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            empPrint=new HashMap();
            if(!empPrint.isEmpty())
                empPrint.clear();

            if(jRadioButton1.isSelected())
                 empPrint.put("PNO",parent.emp.getPAN());
            else
                  empPrint.put("PNO",records.get(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()));

            REPORT="Report.jrxml";
            try {
                JASP_REP =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(REPORT);
                JASP_PRINT=JasperFillManager.fillReport(JASP_REP,empPrint,parent.di.con);
                JASP_VIEW=new JasperViewer(JASP_PRINT,false);
                JASP_VIEW.setVisible(true);
                JASP_VIEW.toFront();
            } 
            catch (JRException excp) {

            }
            setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for time consuming tasks. Using `invokeLater()` just pushes it to the event queue, and it gets run in the EDT, blocking it.

Drawing in swing is done in the event dispatch thread, but since the EDT is busy running your printing task, swing has no chance to process repaint requests.

```
// Note the upped case "Void"s
SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        // Do the printing task here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        // Update the UI to show the task is completed
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: I think that there is no animation timer managed by the code, it is simply done by constructing a `JLabel` with an animated gif `ImageIcon` as the argument.

Comment: would you plz tell how to use SwingWorker. and i am not using Swing TImer. Its simply a JLabel with an Icon.

Comment: @tbodt Something still needs to draw the animation, and have a timer functionality for the purpose, whether it is written by the parent or not. The reason nothing gets drawn is definitely that EDT is blocked, so no `repaint()` request gets processed.

Comment: All right, now you start to make sense. You should mention that you should do the time-consuming task in the `doInBackground` method (the javadoc gives as an example `findTheMeaningOfLife()`) and update the GUI in the `done` method (`label.setText(meaningOfLife)`).

Comment: @ashutosh The link has several examples for using SwingWorkers, from simple to more complicated tasks needing to show interim results. Take a look at the left side menu.

Comment: @tbodt OK, you're right I could be more clear. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` method will not help you in this case. The `Runnable` you pass still gets executed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT, the thread responsible for drawing the UI and responding to clicks etc.).

You could look at SwingWorkers, but you could just as well use a simple `ExecutorService` and pass the `Runnable` to there. The Executor framework - which was added in Java 5 or 6 - offers relatively simple to use tools to have stuff run in the background without having to worry about your own threads. I recommend going with something like this (pseudo code):

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedExecutorService()
....
public void buttonPressed() {
    label.setVisible(true);
    ...
    executor.submit(new Runnable() {
       // create the report etc.
       // DO NOT ACCESS ANY UI COMPONENTS FROM HERE ANYMORE!
       // ...

       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           // update the UI in here
           label.setVisible(false);
       });
    });
}
```

As you can see, `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is used here, too. However, it is called from a background thread to make sure your UI code gets executed on the EDT instead of on the background thread. That is what it is designed for, because UI components must never be accessed (not even read from!) from a background thread. That way you have a convenient mechanism to update you label nevertheless. You could also use it to update some progress bar etc.